# Issue with jQuery plugin datetimepicker not being recognized as date by Date() object wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetimepicker

I have an element where the user is able to pick a date and time using this plugin:

https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/

I am using the following configuration options:

```
$('#startDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:s',
});
```

The output:

```
$("#startDate").val()
```

returns:

```
"2016-02-18T23:59:00"
```

When I attempt to cast this string to the Date() object type like so:

```
Date("2016-02-18T23:59:00")
Date("2016-02-18T23:59:00Z")
Date("2016-02-18T23:59:00+00:00")
```

Date returns this (The current date/time):

```
"Wed Feb 17 2016 14:02:43 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)"
```

How do I get the datetimepicker to return a value that is recognized by the javascript Date() method, or how do I manually convert the returned date to a format recognized by the javascript Date() method?

Comment: _JavaScript Date objects can only be instantiated by calling JavaScript Date as a constructor: calling it as a regular function (i.e. without the new operator) will return a string rather than a Date object; unlike other JavaScript object types, JavaScript Date objects have no literal syntax._ [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Therefore: `var myDate = new Date("2016-02-18T23:59:00");`

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot. Thank you! If you post an actual answer I will accept it immediately.

Comment: @MelanciaUK—that will be interpreted as a local date (or UTC by some, or invalid by others). Do you think the OP wants local or UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
var d = new Date("2016-02-18T23:59:00");
```